# Determining the bifurcation value(s) for a one-parameter family

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let's say we have a one parameter family:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = y^2 + k $$

I want to find the bifurcation value. What does this mean?

It seems like I need to set dy/dt = 0 and then solve for k, but then I get a negative square root:

$$ 0 = y^2 + k $$
$$ y^2 = -k $$
$$ y=sqrt(-k) $$
or
$$ k = -y^2 $$

Is this the right approach?

Comment: How many steady solution can you get for particular $k$? Hint: for some $k$ you get zero, for some two and for one in particular you get only one steady solutions.

Comment: Well, when k=0, y^2=0, which implies y=0 (one stable solution). I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: When does the equation $y^2 = -k$ has real solution $y\in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

- Consider $k$ negative, positive and zero.
- What happens for each of the values to the fixed points?
- What is the bifurcation point defined as from these results?

**Update**

Here are phase portraits for $k = -1, 0, 1$. What do you notice happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, so we use 0 as the base line bifurcation value in this example? And then we observe what happens with the roots when we set k > 0 and k < 0?

Comment: @Bob: Yes, that is correct, I will post phase portraits that I just finished and you can see if you can draw 1-D phase portraits from them.

Comment: Thanks!

When k<0, there is one stable and one unstable equilibrium solution.

When k=0, there is one semi-stable equilibrium solution.

When k>0, there is no equilibrium solution.

Comment: @Bob: Spot on! Regards

Comment: You've been getting a lot of use out of your software for phase portraits! +1